# How to get the number of tuples in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

i want to get the sum of tupples in a list. for an example

```
[("Isuru1","Ranasinghe1",123),("Isuru2","Ranasinghe2",123),("Isuru3","Ranasinghe3",123),("Isuru4","Ranasinghe4",123)]
```

in above list the answer has to be 4.
please help me to solve this. i am new to haskell :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`length`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/length_f.html) function. It gets the length of any list, no matter what's in it.

Example:

```
Prelude> length [("Isuru1","Ranasinghe1",123),("Isuru2","Ranasinghe2",123),("Isuru3","Ranasinghe3",123),("Isuru4","Ranasinghe4",123)]
4
```